Log4j2: is it possible to have an implementation of StrLookup recalculate the returned value on each logging event?
I want to use the StrLookup interface to have the current value of a variable printed into each message logged by log4j2. I suppose it should be easiest to do this by inserting it directly into the PatternLayout of my log4j2.xml.
The problem is that the overriden lookup(...) method of the interface only seems to be called once per class. This call's result is cached and then used for every log call within this class. I would instead like to have the lookup(...) method be recalculated on each log call, since I want to pass dynamic information (e.g. the progress of a process I'm simulating) to the log pattern.
I have the following minimal working example:
@Log4j2
@Plugin(name = "customLog", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
public class Main implements StrLookup {

    @Override
    public String lookup(String key) {
        double d = Math.random();
        System.out.println(d);
        return switch (key) {
            case "simDate" -> String.valueOf(d);
            default -> "<Lookup key not found>";
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
        return lookup(key);
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static Main createLookup() {
        return new Main();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "Hello World!";
        log.info(msg);
        log.warn(msg);
        log.error(msg);
    }
}

My file appender pattern is "[%level] [%c] [%M] - %msg - ${customLog:simDate}%n".
I would expect the three messages to print different random numbers in place of ${customLog:simDate}, but it acutally prints the same number three times:
[INFO] [org.example.Main] [main] - Hello World! - 0.9613408355715877
[WARN] [org.example.Main] [main] - Hello World! - 0.9613408355715877
[ERROR] [org.example.Main] [main] - Hello World! - 0.9613408355715877

Indeed, while debugging I can see that the lookup(String key) method is only called once.
Can I force log4j2 to recalculate the return value on each log call?

As documented in Runtime Property Substitution, the ${...} placeholders in most configuration attributes are evaluated at configuration time.
This means that the effective value of your pattern will be:
[%level] [%c] [%M] - %msg - 0.9613408355715877%n

Some configuration attributes (like the pattern attribute) are also evaluated at runtime. In order to use this feature, you need to escape your placeholder as $${customLog:simDate}. Such a placeholder will be:

Evaluated to ${customLog:simDate} at configuration time.
From there it will be evaluated to whatever you want at each log event.

PS: for performance reason, I would recommend you to implement a custom PatternConverter instead.

Thank you very much! Escaping it with $$instead of $ fixed it! Can you elaborate on the advantages of a custom PatternConverter over just having my class implement StrLookup?

With pattern converters it is easier to obtain a garbage-free configuration, since you obtain a reusable StringBuilder to output your data. Also the %<pattern>{...} syntax needs no escaping to be evaluated at each log event.
